# When to close database connection in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Firstly it may sound like a duplicate question but i didn't get solution i was expecting so I am posting this new question?I have started learning hibernate a couple of days ago.I am stuck on this 1 thing:

Here is my code:

```
public static void open_connection()

sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Listsession = sessionfactory.openSession();
}

public  List select(String qry)
{ 
    open_connection();  
    Listsession.beginTransaction();
    query =Listsession.createQuery(qry);
    list=query.list();
    Listsession.getTransaction().commit();
    Listsession.close();
    sessionfactory.close();
    }
```

**Q1.** I have closed the sessionfactory when a query has run.Is it a good approach?I want to close database connection when we don't need it as we do in JDBC(My teacher taught me that).

**Q2.** Should I close connection when user is getting logout from my site?

**Q3.** Will sessionfactory.close(); also destroy my session variable(session.setattribute("user",ur);).

**Q4.** Does   Listsession.getTransaction().commit(); also close the transaction?

I want to know this because many times i run my project on netbeans i am getting null pointer exception but when i run same project online i don't get null pointer exception and i think this happens because openconnection is called everytime i run my project. 
Sorry for posting so many questions as i couldn't get exact answers i was looking for.

Comment: long-lived-sessions or short-lived-sessions?

Comment: @PeterRader short lived sessions like 20-30 mins.

Comment: 20 min are long-lived-sessions ;D. 5 seconds are short-lived-sessions.

Comment: @PeterRader ok i thougt session timeout -1 is a long session.

Comment: Wait, `long-lived-sessions` and `short-lived-sessions` are patterns how to code Hibernate. Actually you MUST decide if you like to use either short-lived-sessions or long-lived-sessions. Your code is very bad in this case because outside of `select()` n-m relations aswell as lazy-querys wont work because either the session or the connection or the transaction is gone.

Comment: @PeterRader but the user answered below is saying the opposite thing.Secondly i am creating site so I know when i need to run queries so only this select function is called when i need to select something.I am not using lazy queries.Secondly could you explain `Actually you MUST decide if you like to use short-lived-sessions or long-lived-sessions` how should i decide?

Comment: If you are happy, i am happy.

Comment: @PeterRader if you really wanna help kindly move this discussion to chat and help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57833/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-fresher).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.You should close the `Session` but not `SessionFactory`
2.You are already closing `Session` after executing query, so where is the point of again closing when `logout` from site ?
3.`HttpSession` is different from Session in **Hibernate**. `HttpSession` for storing attributes for maintaining user sequence of requests. But `Session` in **Hibernate** to interact with **Database** only. So closing `Session` in **Hibernate** doesn't reflect on `HttpSession`.
4.If you are using `openSession()`, you should close the session manually.But if you are using `getCurrentSession()`, you don't need to bother of it, once transaction committed, session will be closed automatically.
Hope it helps,

Comment: Just one last question what is the difference between  `Listsession.close(); sessionfactory.close();`

Comment: and is it a good approach if i call opensession when user login and close it when user logout.What is best connection or the approach i used above to open connection everytime and close it everytime.

Comment: where `Listsession.close();` defined ? Best connection depends on number of times you hit the database for a single request. If more number of hits use `openSession` else use `getCurrentSession()`

Comment: So you are saying that the above approach is wrong.I should create 1 connection at login and close that on logout.Actually i am unable to understand what you are saying it is a social networking site so number of users will be using it.

Comment: Eg: If a single user logins in, let's assume get data from different tables to show data in different widgets. in that case, open the session in first method querying and close the session in last method query execution.. This is for a single user only.. It is not realted to user login and logout. When you need to fetch the data from database open the connection and close it before you are serving the request.

Comment: Ok so `sessionfactory.close();` closes the database connection and also closes the transaction so i don't need to write `ListSession.close`.

Comment: You should not use until your application exists `sessionfactory.close();'.. and you should always close only Session..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57819/discussion-between-fresher-and-mr-chowdary).